# Using Flexslider 2

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Trying to run Flexslider 2 and it's just displaying a list of the pics. Can't figure out what's wrong..
Is Google still actively hosting the jQuery script? Anyone find any errors?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simpson Strong-Tie</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="images/Architectural Products Group SubCat Image.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/Mudsupply Splash.png">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="images/Quik Drive.jpg">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')
  </script>

  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated as always!

Comment: The issue is SyntaxHighlighter.all();.  Just remove this lines of code and then it start working   $(function() {
      SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `flexslider`. Issue is with `syntaxhighliter` which is not correctly included.

Just remove these lines from your code, then it start working.

```
$(function() {
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});
```

If you want to inlcude `SyntaxHighlighter`  on you page, you need these Basic Steps to follow:-

To get SyntaxHighlighter to work on you page, you need to do the following:

1) Add base files to your page: shCore.js and shCore.css

2) Add brushes that you want (for example, shBrushJScript.js for JavaScript, see the list of all available brushes)

3)Include shCore.css and shThemeDefault.css

4)Create a code snippet with either  or  method (see below)

5)Call SyntaxHighlighter.all() JavaScript method

More information refer to http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html

**Just a Simple Example to Add `flexslider` on you page(This is working on my sample page)**

**Inlcude Div in HTML**

```
<div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="/Images/Image1.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="/Images/Image2.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="/Images/Image3.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="/Images/Image4.png" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**Include JS and css file**

```
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript" defer ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**Inlcude Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(window).load(function () {
              $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide"
              });
           });
        });
  </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CPpBD/

http://flex.madebymufffin.com/index.html

**[EDIT]**

You have to add jquery, and select "onDomready" from dropdown in jsfiddle, then your jsfiddle look like working. see attach screenshot

[image]

Comment: I deleted the line of code you mentioned, it's still not functioning, it's just displaying the pics in a list. Is there something else wrong?

Comment: Just use this one, $(window).load(function () {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide"
            });
        });    remove ,
        start: function(slider) {
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }

Comment: I updated the answer with sample working code to implement flexslider. have a look.

Comment: So should I have the css and js files saved somewhere on my computer? Where is it pointing to with "Scripts" in Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js? I've tried everything and it refuses to work.. If you by any chance could just show me a complete example of the code that would be amazing!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but using your example from jsfiddle, it's now just displaying a bar with a "Next" link. What should I do?

Comment: Not sure, what are you doing??? I give you line by line code, then even jsfiddle for live example.  You have working sample example, Just you need to make it work in your way? Create your current code jsfiddle, then share, I will help you and try to fix for you?

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted your jsfiddle example and pasted into the page I'm working on> I added the javascript component under the links in the <head>. I'm confused where you got this "meta name" part? Sorry obviously I'm a total newb

Comment: Ok, Go to this http://flex.madebymufffin.com/index.html, Create new page, follow step 1 to 3 only

Comment: see updated answer with attach image of jsfiddle. where You have to add jquery, and select "onDomready" from dropdown in jsfiddle, then your jsfiddle example look like working

Comment: that worked. but what changes do I have to make when I enter it into the webpage? I'm just using a simple html editor via Volusion, so there's no option for "onDomready". Do I have to install jQuery or something (that jsfiddle didn't include the link for google's hosted jQuery). Thanks again for all your help/patience